# How to properly chroot when using key based authentication within openssh-server

Tags: ssh, sftp, chroot, sshfs, debian-stretch

I'm running a Debian Stretch x86_64 server, with OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017.

I want to use chroots in combination with OpenSSH server's internal SFTP system. My current setup seems to work, unfortunately excluding the chroot.

I set up an OpenSSH server analogous to [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/431169) on serverfault on a Debian Stretch machine, with the adaptation explained in the [question's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/431171/468474):

```
root@server # grep _NAME /etc/os-release | cut -d= -f2
"Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"

root@server # tail -9 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Use internal sftp server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match group sftponly
     AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u
     ChrootDirectory /srv/sftp/%u
     AllowTcpForwarding no
     PermitTunnel no
     ForceCommand internal-sftp

root@server # stat -c "%a %A" /srv/sftp/sftpuser
700 drwx------
```

Trying to mount the directory via `sshfs` fails, when using the following settings (notice remote path `/`):

```
user@client $ sshfs sftpuser@server.com:/ /mnt -o ssh_command=ssh\ -vvv,sshfs_debug,debug
[...]
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to server.com ([1.2.3.4]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
packet_write_wait: Connection to 1.2.3.4 port 22: Broken pipe
read: Connection reset by peer
```

It works however, when I comment out the `ChrootDirectory` line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and reload the system service `sshd`. Afterwards connecting and accessing the directory has no issues, with the fundamental drawback of not using a chroot, which I want though (notice remote path `/srv/sftp/sftpuser`:

```
user@client $ sshfs sftpuser@server.com:/srv/sftp/sftpuser /mnt; echo $?
0
```

What do I have to change to make the chroot work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `/srv/sftp/sftpuser` directory's permissions, as already explained in [this answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/584993/468474).